# Regex for logic criteria

Tags: regex

I have a input text box to enter a logic criteria. 

Following are the possible inputs:

```
1 OR 2
1 AND 2
(1 OR 2) AND 3
(1 OR 2) OR 3
(1 AND 2) AND 3
(1 AND 2) OR 3
1 AND (2 OR 3)
1 OR (2 OR 3)
1 AND (2 AND 3)
1 OR (2 AND 3)
(1 OR 2) AND (3 OR 4)
(1 OR 2) OR (3 OR 4)
(1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4)
(1 OR 2) AND (3 OR 4) AND (5 OR 6)
```

Can anyone provide a `RegEx` to validate such input?

Comment: what about `(5 OR 6 AND 10 OR 6)`

Comment: @Anirudh That also possible

Comment: Could somebody explain the logic?

Comment: What have you tested? What have you tried? You must try it, not simply ask for someone to resolve your problem, first try to resolve yourself.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but it's not clearly specified. For example, what does `1` etc. stand for? Are those really 1-digit integers? Is nesting possible (`(1 AND (2 OR 3)) OR 4`)? Which language are you using for this? Also, why regex when a parser appears much more suited to the task?

Comment: Can brackets be nested? If yes, regex isn't the *best* solution.

Comment: @sp00m: Why not? Perl/PCRE, PHP, .NET and other regex engines support recursion just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match just *"1 and 2 or 4"*, no parentheses:

```
^\d+(?:\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*\d+)*$
```

Next, instead of each `\d+`, also allow the same expression, wrapped with parentheses:

```
^(?:\d+|\(\d+(?:\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*\d+)*\))(?:\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*(?:\d+|\(\d+(?:\s*(?:AND|OR)\s*\d+)*\)))*$
```

OK - it isn't beautiful, but it works. Obviously, this assume just a single level of parentheses.
As the comments say, depending on your language and requirements you may find a nicer solution.

Working example: http://www.debuggex.com/r/eMBWubl5yAp6hUqQ

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can nest parentheses, you cannot do this with straight regular expressions, because you cannot validate arbitrarily nested parentheses with a regular expression.

The more typical way to validate this input is to break the process into two steps.  Use a family of regular expressions to tokenize the input, and then use a simple grammar to validate the resulting sequence of tokens.  An LALR(1) grammar such as what `yacc` supports makes this problem trivial.

I think there are some extended regex forms that add the necessary functionality that you could match arbitrarily nested parentheses.  I have to admit I'm not readily familiar with any of them, since they quickly get more complicated to use than just writing some looping logic around a much simpler set of matches.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it with looping with my solution. loop this regex `(\({0,1}\d+ (OR|AND) \d+\){0,1})` and repalce all the match value into digit(like 1). until none in the text match `(\({0,1}\d+ (OR|AND) \d+\){0,1})`. if you have only digit then that text is valid, if not it doesn't valid.